# Chance of getting at least type I error out of 4 tests for statistical significance?

Tags: probability, self-study, statistical-significance, binomial-distribution, error

I have a question on a multiple choice that went something like the following:

> Sometimes we can reject null hypotheses even though they are true
>   because by chance the sample data generates a relatively extreme test
>   statistic. If we conduct 4 separate tests of statistical significance,
>   then the probability of obtaining at least one statistical significant
>   result from these tests when all four null hypotheses happen to be
>   true is: ----

My reasoning was that we have a $0.05\%$ chance of committing a type I error - which is what the questions seems to be describing. There are only 4 possible outcomes where we make this $0.05\%$ chance error.

Would something like, $4\cdot(0.05)^4\cdot(0.95)^3$ be appropriate? (Using binomial proabability)

Comment: You are asked for the probability that  _at least_ one Type I error occurs in 4 tests; you have found the probability of _exactly_ one of the tests resulting in a Type I error.

Comment: So, are you saying then that I should have used 1-(0.95^4)?

Answer (score 1):

I'll treat this as [self-study](/questions/tagged/self-study) and provide a hint, since [you are already pretty much done](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/336314/chance-of-getting-at-least-type-i-error-out-of-4-tests-for-statistical-significa#comment635698_336314).

The complement of committing *at least one* type I error is committing *zero* type I errors. What is the probability of committing no type I error in one test? In two (presumed independent) tests? In three? In four? How do you combine this with this being the complement of the event you are looking for?